# Module '[module-name]' already loaded in Unknow:0 (Yii2)

Tags: docker, exception, yii2, ldap

So basically I have been searching for **a lot of time** a way to fix this... *It does not make my application block or something else bad*, but I want to fix, in order to make the application smoother and/or remove errors. Sadly, all the answers from other I saw are **not working** for me

This is the error I get every time I type `./yii` in my docker terminal:

```
PHP Core Warning 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Module 'ldap' already loaded'
in ./Unknown:0

Stack trace:
#0 /dati/www/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/ErrorHandler.php(0): yii\console\ErrorHandler->handleFatalError()
#1 {main}
```

**EDIT1**

I also get this when `composer install`:

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'intl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Module 'intl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'ldap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Module 'ldap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'intl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Module 'intl' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'ldap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Module 'ldap' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

I checked all the .ini files, all the files in conf.d, and yet, there are no duplicates, in fact I deleted the modules, and I still have the same error.
I don't even have the extensions right now, because I did purge them.

If somebody could help me, it would be very nice of you, thanks a lot for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your php configuration, some of the extensions are loaded multiple times.

Check the **php.ini** files for the following rows: `extension=extension_name.so` and remove the duplicates.

Comment: That was not the problem... However, after installing a new project with docker, the problem magically disappeared for my previous project. I don't really know what could have been, but its fixed now.